# Mac 10.5 Python libsvm 64 bit vs 32 bit

Tags: mac, python, libsvm

I have a Mac 10.5
when I type "python" in terminal, it says

> Enthought Python Distribution -- www.enthought.com
>   Version: 7.3-2 (64-bit)
>   Python 2.7.3 |EPD 7.3-2 (64-bit)| (default, Apr 12 2012, 11:14:05) 
>   [GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
>   Type "credits", "demo" or "enthought" for more information.

then I go to my libsvm/python folder and type "make" which results in

> make -C .. lib
>   if [ "Darwin" = "Darwin" ]; then \
>         SHARED_LIB_FLAG="-dynamiclib -W1,-install_name,libsvm.so.2"; \
>     else \
>         SHARED_LIB_FLAG="-shared -W1,-soname,libsvm.so.2"; \
>     fi; \
>     g++ ${SHARED_LIB_FLAG} svm.o -o libsvm.so.2

when I try to do "from svmutil import *" I get the error:

> OSError: dlopen(.../libsvm-3.12/python/../libsvm.so.2, 6): no suitable image found.  Did find:
>     .../libsvm-3.12/python/../libsvm.so.2: mach-o, but wrong architecture

when I do "lipo -info libsvm.so.2", I get:

> Non-fat file: libsvm.so.2 is architecture: i386

So it looks like I'm running 64-bit python but libsvm ends up as a 32-bit program. Any way I can get it to compile as a 64-bit program?